# Site.com builder

Tags: force.com-sites, community, site.com

I have communities enabled on my org. Within the Community I have an option to build pages using Site.com.
Can I use this to also build a salesforce site which is outside the community (has a different salesforce site domain than the community domain)?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. Yes, but you need to create the domain for the site first. Note that if you want the community to be transparently accessible from the Site, it's preferable to make one a subdomain of the other.

Comment: after creating the new site with it's own domain, will I be able to access the Site.com builder? I couldn't find it on the Setup menu.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you use it in a stand alone context. At least that's the way it used to work. At one point it required an additional license. I'm not certain if that's still the case when used with sites. I've not used it recently.